# gcutil getproject returning resource not found

Tags: linux, resources, google-compute-engine, gcloud, gcutil

Does anyone can help me on this error?
I have search the resource not found error with google and read a lot of answers but all the answer not help for me. Like to enable the bill method, yes I have enabled it but not help.

Thannks,
Marmot
[marmot@localhost Projects]$ gcloud auth login
Go to the following link in your browser:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&prompt=select_account&response_type=code&client_id=32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fappengine.admin+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fbigquery+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcompute+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdevstorage.full_control+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fndev.cloudman+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fsqlservice.admin+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fprediction+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fprojecthosting&access_type=offline


Enter verification code: 4/ZUSX5HmO0ivg0B9iJwBM1WNJ9tHd.wpOolknAFYcSXE-sT2ZLcbSVP_2BjAI

You are now logged in as [weisheng.chen@gmail.com].
Your current project is [None].  You can change this setting by running:
  $ gcloud config set project 
[marmot@localhost Projects]$ gcloud config set project marmot-helloworld-1
[marmot@localhost Projects]$ gcutil getproject --project=marmot-helloworld-1 --cache_flag_values --dump_request_response
INFO: --request-start--
INFO: -headers-start-
INFO: accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
INFO: accept: application/json
INFO: user-agent: google-api-python-client/1.0
INFO: -headers-end-
INFO: -path-parameters-start-
INFO: project: marmot-helloworld-1
INFO: -path-parameters-end-
INFO: body: None
INFO: query: ?alt=json
INFO: --request-end--
INFO: URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/marmot-helloworld-1?alt=json
Error: The resource 'projects/marmot-helloworld-1' was not found
[marmot@localhost Projects]$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.14.2-200.fc20.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Apr 28 14:40:57 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

That command is used to get all the information about the Google Compute Engine resources you are using. 
If you want to use that command, you need to enable the Compute Engine APIs, you can do it manually or automatically.

Manually:

1. Visit [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com).
2. Select the project 'marmot-helloworld-1
3. Click on 'APIs & auth'
4. Enable the APIs starting with the text 'Google Compute Engine'

Automatically:

1. Visit [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com).
2. Select the project 'marmot-helloworld-1
3. Click on 'Compute'->'Compute Engine'->'VM instances'

You need to do this the first time, after that you'll be able to run the command and get the appropiate information.

Answer (score 0):

Update: gcutil is deprecated.

For transitioning from gcutil to gcloud compute, refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/transition-gcloud-gcutil). In addition, for more reference to gcloud commands, check this [public documentation link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/).